# Why laminar flow does not produce pouring sound while turbulent flow does

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, flow

I observed in a newly installed tap that it doesn't produce the pouring sound of water (due to a fine mesh on its mouth as I guess)  which made me think that it is related to the type of flow (laminar or turbulent). So I did some tests. What I did was first filled the water with the mug very close to the mouth of the tap which as I guessed shouldn't have produced sound (as it did), because first when the water exits it is in laminar flow and after some time it gets turbulent and from the greater distance it produced sound as before which is because of turbulent flow.
So my question is **Why laminar flow does not produce pouring sound while turbulent flow does**.
I apologize for bad english and thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Turbulent flow moves around more so displaces the air around more.

Comment: Are you giving answer or just a hint as I want some explanation like what force causes particles to hit and produces the sound, etc.

Comment: If that is your question then your question is "What forces causes turbulent flow?", not "why does turbulent flow produce more sound?" In turbulent flow, the water moves around more which just displaces air more. Air being displaced a lot = sound. So the part about turbulent flow making sound isn't too complicated. I have no ideas why turbulent flow happens though.

Comment: No my question isn't what forces cause turbulent flow my question is the same you wrote and your reason doesn't seem to be logical. Sorry if I am asking too dumb question but I am not able to understand how can displacing more air can cause sound because if I wave my hand it also displaces air which doesn't create that much sound.

Comment: Your ears are only sensitive to air vibrations within a frequency range. Your hand doesn't move at high enough frequency to be in that sensitive range or strong/fast enough to have enough power to make up for the low sensitivity of the frequency it is moving at.